# Can ping IP address and nslookup hostname but cannot ping hostname

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, ping

On a windows 2003 server I can `nslookup www.google.com` which returns

```
Server:  localhost
Address:  127.0.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.l.google.com
Addresses:  74.125.79.104, 74.125.79.147, 74.125.79.99
Aliases:  www.google.com
```

I can then `ping 74.125.79.104`:

```
Pinging 74.125.79.104 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 74.125.79.104: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=54
Reply from 74.125.79.104: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=54
Reply from 74.125.79.104: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=54
Reply from 74.125.79.104: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 74.125.79.104:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 15ms, Maximum = 32ms, Average = 19ms
```

But I cannot `ping www.google.com`:

```
Ping request could not find host www.google.com. 
Please check the name and try again.
```

(this one is different from the other question in that this one has a TLD, it is not a local domain.)

Update: I am running a dns server at localhost (127.0.0.1). Even when I change it to use for example opendns, it still can nslookup hostname and ping ip address, but not ping hostname. So what is wrong?

**Update 2: **

here is the ipconfig /all result:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SERVER
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : NETWORK.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : NETWORK.local

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0F-1F-56-3B-AA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.7.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.7.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
```

**Update 3:**

Thanks everyone for their help and suggestions. I appreciate that.

Ipconfig /flushdns returns: Sucessfully flushed the DNS resolver cache

Ipconfig /displaydns returns:

```
2.7.168.192.in-addr.arpa
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : 2.7.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
Record Type . . . . . : 12
Time To Live  . . . . : 0
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
PTR Record  . . . . . : webserver.mydomainname.com


1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa.
Record Type . . . . . : 12
Time To Live  . . . . : 0
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
PTR Record  . . . . . : localhost
```

**Update 4:**

Wireshark shows the following:

```
3   11.540542   208.67.220.220  192.168.7.2 DNS Standard query response A 74.125.79.99 A 74.125.79.104 A 74.125.79.147

6   42.056794   192.168.7.2 192.168.7.255   NBNS    Name query NB WWW.GOOGLE.COM<00>
```

which is weird: when I `ping`, it sends a packet to 192.168.7.255 instead of asking the DNS server for an address

**Update 5:**

This is what netdig had to say:

```
opcode: Query, status: NoError, id: 42
flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

QUESTION SECTION:
www.google.com.                 IN      A       

ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.         86324   IN      CNAME   www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com.       224     IN      A       74.125.79.99
www.l.google.com.       224     IN      A       74.125.79.104
www.l.google.com.       224     IN      A       74.125.79.147

Query time: 0 ms
Server    : 192.168.7.2:53 udp (192.168.7.2)
When      : 1/6/2011 12:33:50 PM
Size rcvd : 100
```

Comment: What does "ipconfig /all" show?

Comment: @Matt H   It's worth saying what you're looking for from ipconfig /all, otherwise analysis is hidden away in your mind and that's not as useful as stating what you'd be looking for from ipconfig /all.

Comment: you could try to wireshark the ping and the nslookup, and compare the results. try to find the packets in which ping tries to resolve the hostname to an ip address (dns uses udp port 53)

Comment: @Weltenwanderer, thanks. See Update 4 above.

Comment: @jao its broadcasting a request to resolve the name in the local subnet. i think its the 

Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : NETWORK.local

thats preventing a dns lookup here. check your tcpip settings for the dns suffixes which should be empty

Comment: The 192.168.7.255 line is doing NetBIOS broadcast name query. See @Weltenwanderer 's answer.

Comment: I've update my question with the netdig results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using yourself (127.0.0.1) as the DNS... Do you really meant it? nslookup will work if your own machine is running a DNS server service.

Make sure the DNS is set correctly at the network adapter.

Comment: +1 I don't understand why this was down-voted. There is surely a DNS problem with localhost.

Comment: The problem is not DNS. If you read carefully you would've seen that I can nslookup a hostname and that ping to the IP address works. However, pinging to the hostname does not work and accessing the URL in the browser does not work. accessing the URL by IP does work.

Comment: I guess most of us read careful enough before we reply here, and if we are not enthusiastic about helping others we won't be here either. Anyways, try ipconfig /flushdns, then ipconfig /displaydns, then try to use netdig and show us the outputs...

Comment: thank you so far. I've updated my question with the requested data. however i could not find a command 'netdig' (or netdiag or net diag)

Comment: google netdig. it's a diagnostic tool for DNS problems

Comment: Can you provide a direct download link please? all sites link to http://www.mvptools.com/ which is unavailable.

Comment: wayback machine =) http://web.archive.org/web/20070123022421/http://mvptools.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, have you set the DNS on the server to 127.0.0.1 because you are using a DNS on the server and have set DNS forwarder that point to your ISP's DNS servers?

If that is the case, you can try a test like this. Set the DNS on the servers adapter to point directly to your ISP's DNS servers. At that point you can do a ipconfig /flushdns and / or reboot and try again. You might get some more information that way....

Comment: I've changed the DNS to the ISP's one, however I still have the same problem.